# Evaluate improper integral: Exponent of square root.

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I was working in a problem in physics, which gave me this integral, and I need solution:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp{\left(-\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}\right)}dx
$$

The problem is, I have no clue how to start. I tried several substitution of variables, none of them successful. If any of you point out some hints of clues, or even how to get to solution, or resources/references/recomendations, it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $x=a\sinh(t)$, then we obtain after using parity of the original integrand

$$
I(a)=2a\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh(t)}\cosh(t)dt
$$

This equals [10.32.9 here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32) and therefore

> $$
> I(a)=2aK_1(a)
> $$

where $K_{\nu}(z)$ denotes a modified Bessel-function of the second type

**Edit**

To make this answer a little bit more self contained, i proof the stated integral representation of the Bessel function

We need to show that

> $$
> F_{\nu}(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh(t)}\cosh(\nu t)dt=K_{\nu}(a) \quad (\star)
> $$

To do so let's have a look at $F^{''}_{\nu}(a)$, where the $'$ denotes a derivative w.r.t. to $a$. We get

$$
F^{''}_{\nu}(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh(t)}\cosh^2( t)\cosh(\nu t)dt=\\
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh(t)}(1+\sinh^2( t))\cosh(\nu t)dt=\\
F_{\nu}(a)+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh(t)}\sinh^2( t)\cosh(\nu t)dt
$$

Here we used $(\star)$ in the last line.
Next let's integrate by parts

$$
F^{''}_{\nu}(a)=F_{\nu}(a)+\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh(t)}(\cosh( t)\cosh(\nu t)+\nu\sinh( t)\sinh(\nu t))dt=\\
F_{\nu}(a)-\frac{1}{a}F^{'}_{\nu}(a)+\frac{\nu}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh(t)}\sinh( t)\sinh(\nu t)dt
$$

Here the first derivative of $(\star)$ was used.
Now another integration by parts reveals
$$
F^{''}_{\nu}(a)=F_{\nu}(a)-\frac{1}{a}F^{'}_{\nu}(a)+\frac{\nu^2}{a^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh(t)}\cosh(\nu t)dt
$$

and therefore

> $$
> F^{''}_{\nu}(a)=F_{\nu}(a)-\frac{1}{a}F^{'}_{\nu}(a)+\frac{\nu^2}{a^2}F_{\nu}(a)
> $$

which means that $F^{''}_{\nu}(a)$  fullfils the [modified Bessel equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25) and $(\star)$ is indeed true. 
To justify that we really have found a rep for $K_{\nu}(a)$ we note that $F_{\nu}(a)$ decays to zero at $a\rightarrow \infty$ in contrast to the other solution of the modified Bessel equation $I_{\nu}(a)$ which is growing exponentially for large arguments.

**QED**

Comment: Amazing. I wonder how have you solve it, that quickly? Ie, what I have to study to solve those types of integrals that faast? =D.

Comment: @Physicist137: Bessel functions, I guess.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I meant actually, arbitrary improper integrals. =).

Comment: @Physicist137
practice,practice,practice! ^^
I also added a proof of the mentioned integral representation of the modified Bessels

Comment: A question.. how have you actually integrated by parts there? (on the first time). I've found no combination of functions $f, g$ from above that complies this:
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)dx = \left[f(x)\int g(x)dx - \int f'(x)\int g(x)dx dx\right]_0^\infty
$$

Comment: @Physicist137 
Try $u(t)=\cosh(\nu t)\sinh(t),\,\,v'(t)=-a \sinh(t) e^{-a\cosh(t)}$